# Get table cell content to move up on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, I have an odd problem trying to align content in 2 columns (achieved using display:table), and have the content in the column div be up top rather than bottom.

Here is my problem -  see the buttons/content on far right are aligned at the BOTTOM of that div:

[image]

Here is how this is achieved - I am trying to do this:

[image]

```
<div class="content">
                <div id = "centered">
                        <div id = "video">
                        <iframe style = "border-width: 0" width="600px" height="600px"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nRG3wWeMqAQ?autoplay=1">
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id = "righted">
                    <p id = "contentTxt"> <strong> Choose </strong>the option that sounds like you.</p>
                    <div class='button -dark'>im a user</div>
                    <div class='button -light'>im a store</div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .content #centered {
         padding-left: 280px;
     }

    /*Divides into 2 sections*/
    #righted {
        display: table-cell;
        padding-left: 2em;
    }

    #centered {
        width: 600px;
        display: table-cell;
        padding-left: 270px;
    }
    #content {
        display: table-row;
    }
```

On the `righted` no matter what I do with margin-top, padding-top, or top it stays on the bottom there. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the vertical align to move the content up

```
#righted {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

and you probably need to remove the margin on the paragraph so it is at the very top and without the default margins from the browser

```
#righted p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vertical-align` property should do what you need here

```css
.content #centered {
  padding-left: 280px;
}


/*Divides into 2 sections*/

#righted {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

#centered {
  width: 600px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 270px;
}

#content {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="centered">
    <div id="video">
      <iframe style="border-width: 0" width="600px" height="600px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nRG3wWeMqAQ?autoplay=1">
                        </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="righted">
    <p id="contentTxt"> <strong> Choose </strong>the option that sounds like you.</p>
    <div class='button -dark'>im a user</div>
    <div class='button -light'>im a store</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical-align: top for #righted

Also you have defined display: table-row for #content but content is not the id of a div so it should be .content

check the edited code

```css
 .content #centered {
         padding-left: 280px;
     }

    /*Divides into 2 sections*/
    #righted {
        display: table-cell;
        padding-left: 2em;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    #centered {
        width: 600px;
        display: table-cell;
        padding-left: 270px;
    }
    .content {
        display: table-row;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
                <div id = "centered">
                        <div id = "video">
                        <iframe style = "border-width: 0" width="600px" height="600px"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nRG3wWeMqAQ?autoplay=1">
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id = "righted">
                    <p id = "contentTxt"> <strong> Choose </strong>the option that sounds like you.</p>
                    <div class='button -dark'>im a user</div>
                    <div class='button -light'>im a store</div>
                </div>
```

Hope it helps